Error Occurs When Configuring Passport Session Store in Express.js with Sequelize and PostgreSQL
I am using Passport for authentication in my Express.js project. The database and ORM I am using are PostgreSQL and Sequelize, respectively.
While configuring session.use() for session handling, I encountered the following error:
An error occurred for attribute sid on model Session.
[cause]: TypeError: Expected type to be a string, a DataType class, or a DataType instance, but got STRING {
options: { length: 36, binary: undefined },
_binary: undefined,
_length: 36

(This is error's screenshot)
enter image description here
**This is the code in the app.js
**
// passport
const passport = require('./config/auth/passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const SequelizeStore = require('connect-session-sequelize')(session.Store);
const { sequelize } = require('./config/database'); // Adjust the path to your Sequelize instance
const Session = require('./modules/auth/models/session'); // Adjust the path to your Session model


app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        //secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
        maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 24 hours
    },
    store: new SequelizeStore({
        db: sequelize,
        tableName: 'Session',
        checkExpirationInterval: parseInt(process.env.SESSION_EXPIRATION_INTERVAL, 10),
        expiration: parseInt(process.env.SESSION_EXPIRATION, 10)
    }),
}));

**This is the code in the model session.js
**
const { DataTypes } = require('@sequelize/core');
const { sequelize } = require('../../../config/database');

const Session = sequelize.define('Session', {
    sid: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(36),
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    expires: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    data: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING(50000),
        allowNull: false,
    },
}, {
    tableName: 'Session', // Custom table name
    timestamps: true, // Includes createdAt and updatedAt
});

module.exports = Session;

Here are what I've tried so far:

Commented the store configuration, and the app runs successfully.

    store: new SequelizeStore({
        db: sequelize,
        tableName: 'Session',
        checkExpirationInterval: parseInt(process.env.SESSION_EXPIRATION_INTERVAL, 10),
        expiration: parseInt(process.env.SESSION_EXPIRATION, 10)
    }),


Changed the type of sid to DataTypes.STRING, but it didn't work
I confirm that there is no Session table that exists in the database before I run the app.
Deleted the Session model and created a Session table with the same definition manually in my database, the issue persisted.
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide a solution!
Thank you in advance!

